# Qt 5 App crashes with "qLineEdit::setText"

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

My app crashes while running to this line in my QMainWindow constructor:

```cpp
ui->timeEdit->setText(QString::number(this->time));
```

To make sure I did nothing wrong with `QString::number(this->time)`, I also tried:

```cpp
ui->timeEdit->setText("QString::number(this->time)");
```

Still doesn't work.

The constructor:

```cpp
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    this->time = 0;
    ui->timeEdit->setText(QString::number(this->time));

    ui->setupUi(this);
}
```

Comment: what is time variable??

Comment: Did you call `setupUi`? From the small snippet, it's hard to tell what's going on.

Comment: Please have a look at [this checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)
and try to edit your question to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Up to now your question is kind of vague, making it hard to see what you are doing and where the problem is.

Comment: I know what's going wrong. This line is before `setupUi`. @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ Thanks.

Comment: @ycao provide a [mre]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you call that line before `setupUI` that means that `timeEdit` object is not yet created causing your application to crash. You should never reference any `ui` objects before the execution of `setupUI`.